# How to get the domain from an URL using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to display a word doc on a webpage. I am using a library named Docx4j to convert .doc to html. This is working fine. But, I'm getting the hyperlinks in the below format.

```
To search on google go to this link [#?] HYPERLINK \"http://www.google.com/\" [#?][#?] google[#?] and type the text.
```

I'm able to convert it to

```
To search on google go to this link  (http://www.google.com) google and type the text.
```

using the below code

```
String myText = "To search on google go to this link [#?] HYPERLINK \"http://www.google.com/\" [#?][#?] google[#?] and type the text.";
System.out.println(myText);
String firstReplace = myText.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("#\\?", "");
System.out.println(firstReplace);
String secondReplace = firstReplace.replaceAll("HYPER\\S+\\s+\"", "(");
System.out.println(secondReplace);
String finalReplace = secondReplace.replaceAll("/*\".", ")");
System.out.println("\n" + finalReplace);
```

Can someone please provide me a regex to convert the above string to

```
To search on google go to this link google (http://www.google.com) and type the text.
```

--EDIT--

There are some links which show up as

```
[#?] HYPERLINK \"http://www.google.com/\" [#?][#?] google page[#?]
```

I should change them to

```
google page (http://www.google.com)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a group reference to match the word `google` which comes after the parenthesis.

You can replace the result of following regex:

```
'(\([^)]*\))\s?(\w+)'
```

With following :

```
'$2 $1'
```

You can use `str.replaceAll()` function for this aim.

Elaboration:

The first capture group `(\([^)]*\))` will match the part between parenthesis, `[^)]*` is a negated character class which match any combination of characters except closing parenthesis.

And the second one `(\w+)` will match the words after that part, `\w+` will match any combination of word characters.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: is there any way I can get "http://www.google.com/" and replace it with "(http://www.google.com/)" directly? I can't use this script given in the question since what I have is an HTML and replacing the " messes up my HTML

Comment: Thanks @Kasramvd. I've edited the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the [#?] markers as early as you do in your question, means that you lose essential information to make the required text adjustments later. The basic template of your input is:

```
[#?] HYPERLINK *target* [#?] [#?] *clickable textual description of link* [#?]
```

So why don't you use those markers to your advantage?

Some regexp like this (NOTE: not tested, probably wrong, but just to give you the basic idea):

```
mystring.replaceAll("\\[#\\?\\] HYPERLINK (.*) \\[#\\?\\] \\[#\\?\\] (.*) \\[#\\?\\]", "$2 ($1)");
```

The above is designed to give you "google page (http://www.google.com)". But I would also question why you want to display it like that. Normally for HTML web pages you want it to be `<a href="http://www.google.com">google page</a>`. To do that, just change the above code.